# How to solve: Dialect 'default' does not support sequence increments in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, insert, auto-increment

I have the following queries:

```
seq = select([tab_setup.columns.ID]).order_by(tab_setup.columns.ID).limit(1)

sel = select([tab_Global.columns.ID_UNIQUE.label('DL_ID'), tab_Global.columns.CV_CNV.label('DL_Conv')]) \
        .where(tab_Global.columns.CV_CNV.isnot(None))

stmt = tab_setup.insert().from_select(['DL_ID', 'DL_Conv',next_value(Sequence(seq))] , sel)
```

As far as I have understood, the problem is related to autofill the ID (autoincrement) field within the table "tab_setup". 
Which is the correct way to pass the values?

The ID field is a normal auto-increment field of 1 per row.

Using the Sequence function only, it is raising an error that suggest to use "next_value"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add in the select query:

func.row_number().over(order_by=tab_Global.columns.ID_UNIQUE)).label('ID')

This will generate a sequential number for any row; then if the starting number is not 1 I create the variable start_from = 10 and complete the above with: (start_from  + func.row_number()...)